# Unable to sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity for a Cognito user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I have a simple use case to authenticate a user using AWS Cognito and the assume a role to be able to do something useful (read from S3 in my case). Apparently I am missing something very obvious.

I am using pure web http client with cognito authentication (so Cognito can federate other identity providers) and the backend receive only the id_token.

I could get session credentials using `getCredentialsForIdentity`, apparently this credentials have assigned permissions from the role defined by the Cognito identity pool (in my case Cognito_demoidpoolAuth_Role)

My idea was creating another role which the federated web identity could assume.

So I created a new role for Web Identity, the role to access the data has Trust Relationship with following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-central-1:500a5721-abca-xxxx-xxxx-c15625a7xxxx"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Following code should assume the role needed to read from the bucket

```
WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider credProvider = new WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider(
   idToken,
   null,
    "arn:aws:iam::535544306598:role/docmgr-test-role" );
```

under the hood this object calls assumeRoleWithWebIdentity and I get following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: 
Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService;
 Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 059e56ee-25c8-11e8-8852-f7ca4d49742b)
```

Calling directly STS assumeRoleWithWebIdentity with the id_token ends with the same result, so apparently I have set wrong policy or trying to do things wrong way.